# C# convert AVRO to JSON

Tags: c#, json, avro

Is there C# implementation to convert an AVRO deserialized

```
<GenericRecord>
```

back into a regular JSON format?  I have successfully read the topic from Kafka and used the `AvroDeserializer` but I want to convert that into a JSON format.

Here's an example:
Simple JSON:

```
{       
        "value": {
            "eventCreatedTimestamp": 1588694347577,
            "iouDecision": "PLANE",
            "iouDecisionReason": {
                "value": "Optimal"
            }
        }
    }
```

Same from the AVRO deserialized Generic.Record:

```
{Schema: 
{"type":"record","name":"TheCustomerDecisionEvent",
"namespace":"com.farmxxx.tst.property.service.options.iou.messaging.avro","fields":
[{"name":"eventCreatedTimestamp","type":["null","long"]},
{"name":"iouDecision","type":["null",{"type":"enum",
"name":"TheType",
"namespace":"com.farmxxx.tst.property.service.options.iou.messaging.avro",
"symbols":["HRMR","FIELD","PLANE"]}]},
{"name":"iouDecisionReason","type":["null",{"type":"record","name":"iouDecisionReason",
"namespace":"com.farmxxx.tst.property.service.options.iou.messaging.avro",
"fields":[{"name":"value","type":["null","string"]}]}]}]}
,
 contents: { eventCreatedTimestamp: 1588694347577, 
 iouDecision: Schema: {"type":"enum","name":"TheType",
 "namespace":"com.farmxxx.tst.property.service.options.iou.messaging.avro",
 "symbols":["HRMR","FIELD","PLANE"]}, value: PLANE,
 iouDecisionReason: Schema: {"type":"record","name":"iouDecisionReason",
"namespace":"com.farmxxx.tst.property.service.options.iou.messaging.avro",
"fields":[{"name":"value","type":["null","string"]}]}, contents: { value: Optimal, }, }}
```

So the task is to get back to the Simple JSON from the AVRO Generic.Record.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/kristofferjalen/AvroConverter

Comment: Would you know the function call

Comment: You mean something else than what's in the readme?

Comment: Thanks anyway -- I'll take it a different way.

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be found using:

https://github.com/AdrianStrugala/AvroConvert

> `Avro2Json` feature.

With this you can read a topic from Kafka and translate that into simple JSON.
I use that simple JSON to pass onto other clients who don't want to know about AVRO record format etc.

Many thanks to the author of the AvroConvert Github repository.

Comment: PS: it's not a free tool

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I've used https://github.com/kristofferjalen/AvroConverter for this in the past (I have no affiliation with the project).

The README for that page indicates it's quite easy to use. Simply install its package from NuGet by entering `Install-Package AvroConverter` on the Package Manager command line (or your CLI if not using Visual Studio), then call it with the following from your code:

```cs
var path = @"C:\your\avro\file\path.avro";
var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
var json = AvroConvert.ToJson(fileInfo);
```

Comment: This works on files but I'm receiving a Kafka topic which means I'm dealing with one record at a time.  The deserialized Avro Generic record has the schema embedded in it.  That is by design for Avro but it's not what you would want when communicating with other clients who just want simple JSON not and the other schema details which I'm trying to strip from the Avro record and pass along just the simple JSON key: value pair  thanks

Comment: I don't know that your use of a single or several records matters as the source indicates it supports reading from a stream as well. If it's just a matter of excluding some of the deserialized properties from the record, and you know the shape of the data you're receiving, why not simply map the resulting deserialized JSON to a cleaner object without the additional schema fields?

Comment: I'm trying to make the JSON object generic and not map it to a specific object.  Just be able to pass this to another client who does not want to know about AVRO and the embedded schema.  I could show an example if that helps

Comment: It seems that if you've got the data in JSON per the above, now you're faced with the challenge of just deserializing that to a stronger type and you've got more tooling for this in the JSON -> .NET space than AVRO -> .NET. Why can't you just store the JSON as-is and ignore any of the excess whenever you subsequently convert that to your strongly typed object? Presumably you have an idea of the realm of types it can deserialize to, or you have type information in the object anyway.